# Android chat message dont show up

Tags: java, android, sockets, client, client-server

I have problem with client/server app. 
Client is on android and server is java app.

When I start server and clients on java desktop app everything is fine. But when I start android app there is bugs. Message from server are visible on the android but message (from android itself or other clients) are not.

[Android app look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziVhd.png) || [What communicates should be here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bwoo.png)

There are no errors but messages dont show up.

**@update**
On android i cant see also message from client itself but also from other chat clients. I only see if someone new join to chat. I think is something wrong with communication? But i dont know what.

**@update2**
I notice that program don't execute this part of code

```
 protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            message = params[0].toString();
            Log.e("CLIENT","Message In Background: "+message);
            if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
                out.println(message);
                out.flush();
                Log.e("CLIENT","Message send"+message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I call it but in log monitor I dont get messages from Sender class

```
Log.e("CLIENT","Create sender");
Sender sender = new Sender();
sender.execute(message);
Log.e("CLIENT","sender.execute");
```

Messages:

```
01-17 17:15:39.330 8232-8232/com.example.testmulti E/Home: Application start
01-17 17:15:39.596 8232-8259/com.example.testmulti E/EGL_emulation: tid 8259: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-17 17:15:52.137 8232-8232/com.example.testmulti E/ServerIP: Server ip is: 192.168.0.102
01-17 17:15:52.266 8232-8232/com.example.testmulti E/MainActivity: Start Main Activity
01-17 17:15:52.325 8232-8262/com.example.testmulti E/serverAddr: /192.168.0.102
01-17 17:15:52.325 8232-8262/com.example.testmulti E/TCP Client: C: Connecting...
01-17 17:15:52.342 8232-8262/com.example.testmulti E/TCP Server IP: 192.168.0.102
01-17 17:15:52.343 8232-8262/com.example.testmulti E/TCP Client: C: Sent.
01-17 17:15:52.343 8232-8262/com.example.testmulti E/TCP Client: C: Done.
01-17 17:15:52.560 8232-8259/com.example.testmulti E/EGL_emulation: tid 8259: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-17 17:15:59.416 8232-8232/com.example.testmulti E/MainActivity: Button was clicked
01-17 17:15:59.417 8232-8232/com.example.testmulti E/CLIENT: Create sender
01-17 17:15:59.419 8232-8232/com.example.testmulti E/CLIENT: sender.execute
```

So it dosent execute **sender.execute(message);**

How to repeir that?

---

MainActivity

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);

        mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        new connectTask().execute("");        
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                if (mClient != null) {
                    mClient.sendMessage(message);
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

    }


    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,Client> {

            @Override
            protected Client doInBackground(String... message) {
                mClient = new 

            Client(new Client.OnMessageReceived() {

                @Overrid
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mClient.run();            
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            arrayList.add(values[0]);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Client class

```
public void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        Sender sender = new Sender();
        sender.execute(message);
    }


public void run() {
        mRun = true;
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            Log.e("serverAddr", serverAddr.toString());
            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            Log.e("TCP Server IP", SERVERIP);
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();
                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);}
                    serverMessage = null;
                }
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '"
                        + serverMessage + "'");
            } catch (Exception e) {Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
                }finally {socket.close();}
                     } catch (Exception e) {Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);}        
    }

public class Sender extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
    {

        private String message;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            message = params[0].toString();            
            if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
                out.println(message);
                out.flush();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add the message to your list in your send's onClick?

```
[...]
arrayList.add(message);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
[...]
```

Comment: Yes but on android i cant see message from other clients
And on java clients I cant see android messages.

Comment: Did you add the line in your send's onClickListener?